# Why the hint type doesn't work with collect? Only the turbofish syntax?

Tags: rust

I just discovered something that I thought wasn't like that (in fact I wasted so much time fixing it).

I would like to understand with your help where I went wrong and if I understood correctly.

So I'm in love with the `?` error handling (I don't know how I lived without it in other languages!).

But using a `collect()` I thought it was the same:

```rust
pub fn get_players(input: &PlayerInput) -> Result<Option<Vec<Player>>> {
    if let Some(input_players) = input.players.as_ref() {
        let players: Result<Vec<Player>> = input_players
            .iter()
            .map(|x| {
                Player::new(x.id.as_deref(), &x.code, &x.name)
            })
            .collect()?;

        Ok(Some(players))
    } else {
        Ok(None)
    }
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src\player\get.rs:55:17
    |
55  |         Ok(Some(players))
    |            ---- ^^^^^^^^ expected struct `Vec`, found enum `Result`
    |            |
    |            arguments to this enum variant are incorrect
    |
    = note: expected struct `Vec<_>`
                 found enum `Result<Vec<_>, common::error::Error>`
help: the type constructed contains `Result<Vec<Player>, common::error::Error>` due to the type of the argument passed
   --> src\player\get.rs:55:12
    |
55  |         Ok(Some(players))
    |            ^^^^^--------^
    |                 |
    |                 this argument influences the type of `Some`
```

So reading the web I found out that I need to use the turbofish syntax to make it work, instead of the type hint, like this:

```rust
pub fn get_players(input: &PlayerInput) -> Result<Option<Vec<Player>>> {
    if let Some(input_players) = input.players.as_ref() {
        // let players: Result<Vec<Player>> = input_players
        let players = input_players
            .iter()
            .map(|x| {
                Player::new(x.id.as_deref(), &x.code, &x.name)
            })
            // .collect()?;
            .collect::<Result<Vec<Player>>>()?;

        Ok(Some(players))
    } else {
        Ok(None)
    }
}
```

But why is this? Why the hint type doesn't work here?

Comment: Because you're using the wrong type for the variable. `?` removes the `Result`.

Comment: If I remove the `Result` (using the correct hint type) there is another error (I don't remember what, right now).

Comment: Ah, you're right. This is why making [minimum reproducible examples](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e6c9afd7728f1099a8d335b43766c603) pays off. I guess it can't be done without a turbofish if you have a `?` after. If you absolutely detest the turbofish[...](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5955ca520ec1c9e1ffc8394b6423d0c9)

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you are using `?` obscured the compiler. Multiple types can have `?` applicable to functions returning `Result`: you could write your own such type (well, it requires nightly because the [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) trait is experimental, but it is possible). So, the compiler thinks that you may be `collect()`ing into a different type that also implements `FromIterator` and `Try`.

Answer (score 2):

This code needs updating if you're using `?`, as the `Result` is now split into either a return value, or the `Ok` part is assigned. All that's left after `?` is the `Ok` part:

```rust
let players: Vec<Player> = input_players // No longer Result<...>
    .iter()
    .map(|x| { ... })
    .collect()?;
```

If you let the compiler figure it out with just `let players = ...` it will probably work out as expected.

What the compiler's saying is "I don't know how to collect a `Result` from this iterator".

You can either hint on the assignment, or the turbofish, or both, but if both they have to agree on what's going on.

The compiler should be able to figure out that the only thing that `players` can be is `Vec<Player>` which should work out, but if it doesn't, then it's hint time.

Comment: The question is: can I use the hint type alone? Without the turbofish? Why not?

Comment: You can, but you need to get the right type. Your code insists it's getting a `Result` when it clearly isn't.